# This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classPrivateMethods'

Tags: eslint

I am getting this error. There are a few similar cases that I have seen in Stackoverflow, but I checked and tried everything and the solutions didn't work.

The project itself works, it is just when I try to use [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), I am getting the error:

```
> pkg src/index.js --target=latest-win-x64 --out-path ./dist --config pkg.json
:
:
> Error! This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classPrivateMethods' (441:2)
  E:\Proj\node_modules\node-webpmux\webp.js
```

All solutions basically say to add `plugin-proposal-class-properties` and `plugin-proposal-private-methods`, and specify them in the project json files (eslint, babel, package). I did that, and it doesn't help.

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0"
  },
```

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 12,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "babelOptions": {
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
         "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"]
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "classPrivateMethods",
        "classPrivateProperties",
        "babel"
      ],    
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1,
      "babel/semi": 1
    }
  }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
  }
```

.pkg.json:

```
{
    "name": "WA chatbot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "pkg": {
        "assets": "./assets"
    }
}
```

node version: v14.15.3

yarn: v1.22.10

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? Currently struggling myself with pkg.